# Get the repository path in kettle

Tags: pentaho, etl, kettle

I struggle to get the full repository path which kettle is using. Reading the help on variables ([link](http://wiki.pentaho.com/display/EAI/.07+Variables)) states that I could use either "*Internal.Transformation.Repository.Directory*" or "*${Internal.Job.Repository.Directory}*" depending on if it is a job or a transformation. This actually works and returns the path to the file with the repo as root.
Since I need the "full path" to the file (or the repo) - I tried the "${Internal.Job.Filename.Directory}" (and the transformation one) but this returns the string "Parent Job File Directory" (see below).
As additional information - I am connected to a repo.

[image: Wanted the path :(]

Mission - How to get the full path to the file (job/transformation)?

Comment: Do I understand correctly?  You are connected to a repository in which you have a job named myJob which calls a transfo called myTrans. In myTransfo you need a variable containing the full path of myJob ?

Comment: Hello - that is exactly the case. We would like to use two different db connections, which we store in kettle.properties. To read these and have the job use the correct environment (prod/test) we would like to read the file with the db information. To read the file we would need the path - so you are correct!

Comment: I did proposed a solution, however I wonder if to read (ad parse) the transformation file it is the easiest solution for your use case. Please ask support for your specific use case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory of the caller of the transformation is the ${Internal.Entry.Current:Directory}. This is because a job can contains a job so what matters is the directory of the entry in the job.

Note: If you run the transformation directly, rather that call it from a job, the Internal.Job.Filename.File will be the generic "Parent Job File Name" rather that "".

[image]

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer proposal - I think there is more to it (like if being connected to a repo or not). I used the component "Get Parameter" and attached the actual path as parameter to the shell. Now I can access it by going through a transaction reading it.